# unix timestamp in sphinx rt index

Tags: php, sphinx

I'm using RT index and I'll be using rt_attr_uint to hold unix timestamp, is that ok?

Below is what I mean,

```
#rtindex
type = rt
path = /var/data/sphinx/idx
rt_attr_uint = timestamp
```

Then will use php time() function to insert the time to the field, something like the following

```
$mysqli->query("insert into idx values ( time() ) ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work.

`$pdo->query('INSERT INTO idx VALUES(' . time() . ')');`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how it works as it uses signed int, do you think it will work with the uint used by sphinx? will it mess things up?